# using @property in ARC

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, instance-variables

When I declare a property without a storage specification + instance variable, everything works happily:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSSomething* mySomething;
}
@property (readonly) NSSomething* mySomething;
```

Yet, when I delete the instance variable declaration, I get a compilation error stating that I must specify the storage type:

```
@property (readonly, strong) NSSomething* mySomething;
```

This made me wonder should I just declare strong, but it should be readonly anyway..
What is happening here? Which is approach should I use for which case?

**EDIT (For those unable to replicate the problem):**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't replicate that, is there any other information you can supply? Here's the code I tried: http://pastebin.com/4Mj1rzHd (compiled with `clang -fobjc-arc Untitled.m -framework Foundation`)

Comment: For others unable to reproduce this, I believe this was an issue localized to the version of the LLVM compiler shipping with Xcode 4.2, and you are no longer warned about this in 4.3+. I've run into this with framework code that I've written under 4.3, but people have complained about compile errors under 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it right. If you want it readonly, leave the readonly in there for sure.

If you want the ivar to be synthesised for you, though, the compiler needs to know whether to make it strong, weak, or unsafe untrained. The default is assign which translates to unsafe unretained (which probably isn't what you want). Others are reporting that the compiler handles the default properly without warning, but since you're having trouble, you need the retain attributes in the property declaration.

Alternatively, you can declare the ivar yourself as you originally did.

Comment: The compiler defaults to `assign`, see my comment to @user1258240. From the Apple docs: "assign Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. This attribute is the default."

Comment: Assign equates to unsafe unretained. This is likely not what you want. The compiler is making you be explicit here so you don't make a mistake.

Comment: I agree that it is probably not what is wanted. I created a test iOS ARC project and can not replicate the problem and according to Apple docs no setter semantic should be required. Have you replicated the problem?

Comment: Nope. I didn't try yet, though. I guess it could be a difference between versions. They've changed a lot recently.

Comment: Crap, I guess I fail for using LLVM 3.0, not updating to LLVM 3.1? Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify either strong or weak, depending on whether you are willing that yourSomething will vanish when someone else stops referencing to it. If the property is based on an instance variable the property is automatically strong.

Also, independently of above decision, you should set the property to read only if you don't want it to have a setter (so nobody will be able to set yourObject.yourSomthing=something). This means that (unless you privately redeclare the property as readwrite in the .m file) there is no way to directly set yourSomething to anything. This can be useful if the getter doesn't rely on a variable but instead computes the returned value by some other means.

Comment: Can you explain and provide documentation for the statement: "If the property is based on an instance variable the property is automatically strong."? `assign` is the default setter semantic. See: [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

Comment: There's no contradiction.strong means that the property pointer points strongly to the object, which is the case for an ivar: it isn't released before the object pointing to it is. If it also has the assign property it means that my object.property=something sets the property variable to point to something: this is in contrast to copy, for example, where the same operation would make a copy of something and make the property point to the new something (either strongly or weakly, depending on whether the property is strong or weak)...

Comment: "If it also has the assign property" is incorrect, there can be only one setter semantic. From the Apple doc mentioned above: "Setter Semantics: These attributes specify the semantics of a set accessor. They are mutually exclusive." `strong` means if there is a `@synthesize` directive it will create code that matches the property keywords.

Comment: sorry, you are (partially) right. assign however is only for scalar values, not for referenced values at all. For NSSomething *, as in the question, I think it's still irrelevant and that my answer still holds.

Comment: it probably will, although I'm not sure why you mention this here.

Comment: As demonstrated by your hedging about the sun rising it seems you have trouble agreeing with statements by others. In my experience most people would agree that the sun will rise tomorrow. :-)